# Creation of AMI from operating wordpress site yield "connection refused" with elastic ip

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, elastic-ip

I created an AWS server and installed wordpress with an elastic ip address and verified that the default website was up and running.

I wanted to make a backup image at that point so that I could use it as a beginning point for other websites.  However, after getting the AMI running and attaching the elastic ip address to it, I got an "connection refused" error.  I can both SSH and FTP into the server, but the wordpress site is offline.  I then switched the elastic ip back to the original server and got the exact same issue.

I'm guessing that this is a "change of ip" type error(?) (although, when I've seen that before, the connection has never been outright refused... it usually allows at least access to the admin area of the website) but I thought by using an elastic ip address that I would avoid that. I'm also confused by the error in the first server, since the database still has that address.

Any ideas about how to troubleshoot something like that?  Is there anything else that it could be?

Answer (score 1):

Well.... I missed something vital.

Using an AMI works just fine with an elastic ip address.  I had forgotten to make sure the webserver (httpd) and mysqld were running with :
**service httpd restart**

and

**service mysqld restart**

What made it click was reading that the main reason for this error is that there is listener to the incoming data. 
Duh.